# wasm openssl get dlopen abort

Tags: openssl, emscripten, webassembly

I complie openssl1.1.1c to do some encrypt and decrypt in browser.Here is my build script.
`emconfigure ./Configure linux-x32 -no-asm -no-threads`

`sed -i 's|^CROSS_COMPILE.*$|CROSS_COMPILE=|g' Makefile`

`emmake make -j 12 build_generated libssl.a libcrypto.a apps/openssl`

And i got two bitcode file  `libcrypto.so` and `libssl.so`,then i use it in my own code.
Here is my CMkaeLists.txt:

`include_directories("${OPENSSL_ROOT}/build/include")`
`link_directories("${OPENSSL_ROOT}/lib")`

`set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "--pre-js pre.js -s WASM=1  -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='[\"cwrap\",\"getValue\",\"setValue\"]'"`

`SET(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX ".html")`

`add_executable(SM2FinalNew main.c ${DIR_SRCS})`

`target_link_libraries(SM2FinalNew crypto)`

When i use sha256 base64 ,everything is ok,but when i use some method to achieve sm2 encrypt and decrypt,i got error on the web page.

`SM2FinalNew.html:98 To use dlopen, you need to use Emscripten's linking support, see https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/wiki/Linking`

I found when i call `EC_POINT_mul` method in `openssl/ec.h`, the error apper,when i comment the `EC_POINT_mul` call，the error disapper,but the encrypt result is incorrect.
I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like somewhere the code you are compiling is trying to use `dlopen` to load an external library.  Emscripten's support for shared libraries and dynamic linking is fairly limited.  Your best bet is to find the code in question and try to statically link the required library instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I found that when i build openssl with option no-engine and no-dso ,the error disapper,I don't konw why.I think in openssl somewhere ,it call dlopen function.